# Query to filter out data based off certain time frame

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to figure out how to write a query in T-SQL where I want to filter out data based off the time range. Here is the data shown in the image below. Each row is a session and each session has a date/time range. I want to exclude any data that would occur during or within between 2am - 4am. Here's the query I wrote but the problem is that it will still include the data if the EndDate last over 1 day and then passes the 2am - 4am timeframe. The first highlight is a great example. The ones that are highlighted is supposed to be excluded.

Here is the query I wrote. When running the query, the first row was still not excluded, which is supposed to be. Is there a way to fix this problem?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE CAST(StartDate as TIME) NOT BETWEEN '2 am' AND '4 am'
    AND
    CAST(EndDate as TIME) NOT BETWEEN '2 am' AND '4 am'
    AND
    DATEDIFF(HH,StartDate, EndDate) < 24
```

Sample Data:

```
City    Country StartDate   EndDate
Atlanta US  8/22/2020 23:30 8/23/2020 4:30
Atlanta US  8/22/2020 23:00 8/23/2020 1:30
Dallas  US  8/22/2020 10:30 8/22/2020 17:30
Miami   US  8/22/2020 5:30  8/22/2020 12:00
Los Angeles US  8/23/2020 14:00 8/24/2020 1:20
New York    US  8/25/2020 1:00  8/25/2020 4:30
New York    US  8/22/2020 1:30  8/22/2020 2:30
Miami   US  8/21/2020 15:30 8/21/2020 23:30
Seattle US  8/22/2020 4:30  8/22/2020 23:30
Seattle US  8/26/2020 3:30  8/26/2020 4:30
```

Expected Result.

```
City    Country StartDate   EndDate
Atlanta US  8/22/2020 23:00 8/23/2020 1:30
Dallas  US  8/22/2020 10:30 8/22/2020 17:30
Miami   US  8/22/2020 5:30  8/22/2020 12:00
Los Angeles US  8/23/2020 14:00 8/24/2020 1:20
Miami   US  8/21/2020 15:30 8/21/2020 23:30
Seattle US  8/22/2020 4:30  8/22/2020 23:30
```

Comment: Please consider posting your data as DDL/DML statements or at least as formatted text so we can copy and paste it out.

Comment: Hi @DaleK, I have added the data as a formatted text. Thanks!

Comment: If you add your expected result it would help clarify "exclude any data that would occur during or within between 2am - 4am". Does that mean you want to split the first row (8/22 23:30 to 8/24 04:30) into rows with 8/22 23:30 to 8/23 02:00, 8/23 04:00 to 8/24 02:00 and 8/24 04:00 to 8/24 04:30?

Comment: Sorry @DaleK , the EndDate of the first highlighted row is 8/23. Not 8/24. I have updated the data set.

Comment: Hi @HABO, I will add the expected result.

Comment: Hi @DaleK. My apologies. I have updated the results. Yes, the second New York should be excluded as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK this might not be the simplest solution but it works.

Basically this query finds the next relevant 2am following the `StartDate` so if `StartDate` is after 4am, then its 2am the next day, if its before 2am then its today. If that relevant 2am is after the `EndDate` then the row is OK, it doesn't overlap the window. If its not after then we have an overlap.

In order to calculate this difference we have to work out whether the 2am occurs today or tomorrow, hence the add 1 day.

And your existing logic works for when either `StartDate` or `EndDate` falls within the window.

```
declare @Test table (City varchar(24), Country varchar(12), StartDate datetime, EndDate datetime);

insert into @Test (City, Country, StartDate, EndDate)
values
('Atlanta','US','8/22/2020 23:30','8/23/2020 4:30'),
('Atlanta','US','8/22/2020 23:00','8/23/2020 1:30'),
('Dallas','US','8/22/2020 10:30','8/22/2020 17:30'),
('Miami','US','8/22/2020 5:30','8/22/2020 12:00'),
('Los Angeles','US','8/23/2020 14:00','8/24/2020 1:20'),
('New York','US','8/25/2020 1:00','8/25/2020 4:30'),
('New York','US','8/22/2020 1:30','8/22/2020 2:30'),
('Miami','US','8/21/2020 15:30','8/21/2020 23:30'),
('Seattle','US','8/22/2020 4:30','8/22/2020 23:30'),
('Seattle','US','8/26/2020 3:30','8/26/2020 4:30');

select *
from @Test
where cast(StartDate as time) not between '2 am' and '4 am'
and cast(EndDate as time) not between '2 am' and '4 am'
and dateadd(day, case when cast(StartDate as time) > '04:00:00' then 1 else 0 end, dateadd(hh, 2, convert(datetime,convert(date, StartDate)))) >= EndDate;
```

Note: I haven't tested edge cases such as then the EndDate is exactly 2am or the StartDate is exactly 4am - I leave that to you.

Comment: What happens if the StartDate is after 2am but before 4am?

Comment: @Dee Your original condition handles that. My improvement only handles the case your original conditions didn't catch.

Answer (score 0):

Only the last is going to be filtered out.  You conditions are equivalent to:

```
WHERE CAST(StartDate as TIME) NOT BETWEEN '2:00:00' AND '4:00:00' AND
      CAST(EndDate as TIME) NOT BETWEEN '2:00:00' AND '4:00:00' AND
      DATEDIFF(hour, StartDate, EndDate) < 24
```

All are within 24 hours.  For the first two, the start time is obviously not in the range.  And the stop time is 4:30:00, which misses the exclusion time frame by 30 minutes.

The last looks like it will be filtered out by the logic.

EDIT:

If you don't want an overlap, then I would suggest:

```
WHERE ( (CAST(StartDate as TIME) >= '04:00:00' AND
         (CAST(EndDate as TIME) > CAST(StartDate as TIME) OR
          CAST(EndDate as TIME) < '02:00:00' 
         )
        ) OR
        (CAST(StartDate as TIME) < '02:00:00' AND
         CAST(EndDate as TIME) < '02:00:00' 
        )
       ) AND
       EndDate < DATEADD(day, 1, StartDate)
```

The last condition is needed only if the span can exceed one day.

```
NOT BETWEEN '2:00:00' AND '4:00:00' AND
      CAST(EndDate as TIME) NOT BETWEEN '2:00:00' AND '4:00:00' AND
      DATEDIFF(hour, StartDate, EndDate) < 24
```

Comment: I just want to exclude any data that would occur within that time frame or been apart of that time frame regardless of the date. For example. For the first row, the start date started at 8/22/20 23:30 but ended at 8/23/20 04:30. So that being the time frame, it occur during that time frame, therefore should be excluded. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Dee . . . No, that was not clear to me.  But it seems to be clear to someone else.